# One parameter of JSON out put is null value

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure for receive json string .
but my result had `NULL` value for `Price` . In below you can test it :

```
Declare @json nvarchar(4000) = N'{"productid":3,"startdate":"2020-01-05","Price":12.00,"unittype":10,"flag":1}'

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #PriceTemp 
if ISJSON(@json) > 0

    SELECT * into #PriceTemp 
    FROM OPENJSON(@json)
    With (  ProductID   int         '$.productid'
            ,StartDate  date        '$.startdate'
            ,Price      money       '$.price'
            ,UnitType   bigint      '$.unittype'    
            ,Flag       int         '$.flag'
        )
```

```
Select * from #PriceTemp
```

Result :

[image]

What's the wrong?

Comment: Json is case-sensitive. you should change `$,price` to `$.Price`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `OPENJSON()` with explicit schema definition, the [syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax) for the column definitions are case-sensitive. You need to use `$.Price` in your explicit schema:

```
SELECT * into #PriceTemp 
FROM OPENJSON(@json
WITH (  
   ProductID   int         '$.productid'
   ,StartDate  date        '$.startdate'
   ,Price      money       '$.Price'
   ,UnitType   bigint      '$.unittype'    
   ,Flag       int         '$.flag'
)
```

If you aren't sure about the capitalization of the first character in the JSON input, one possible solution is to use `OPENJSON()` with default schema and aggregation. Note, that in this case `OPENJSON()` returns a table with columns `key`, `value` and `type` and the data type for the `value` column is `nvarchar(max)`.

```
SELECT 
   productid = MAX(CASE WHEN LOWER([key]) = 'productid' THEN [value] END),
   startdate = MAX(CASE WHEN LOWER([key]) = 'startdate' THEN [value] END),
   price = MAX(CASE WHEN LOWER([key]) = 'price' THEN [value] END),
   unittype = MAX(CASE WHEN LOWER([key]) = 'unittype' THEN [value] END),
   flag = MAX(CASE WHEN LOWER([key]) = 'flag' THEN [value] END)
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
```

Comment: thanks... (back-end /front-end)  send to database json files. how i can parameter validation by json. if i check #pricetemp data, sp get to slow entry data process. i'm not expert to use json in sql.

Comment: @Amirhossein Another possible solution in the updated answer.